# How to fix show location button in android - React Native Map?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I have some issue with Location Button I used react native maps *Airbnb* in my App,
when the first time I open the app and a map is rendered the button is disappeared but when I close the app * still in background * and reopen them the button appeared well like this GIF,

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0xLa.jpg

**Note**

> I have seen all the issues same in the main repo of react native maps
>   but it's not working!

**And other Q,**

The App didn't ask me to open the **GPS** for the first time, just work when I opened **manually**
I have Android 8 * real device *

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

let { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const LATITUDE = 31.78825;
const LONGITUDE = 34.4324;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.0421;

class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            width: width,
            marginBottom: 1,
            region: {
                latitude: LATITUDE,
                longitude: LONGITUDE,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            }
        };

    }
    _findMe = async () => {


        this.watchID = await navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            ({ coords }) => {
                const { latitude, longitude } = coords
                this.setState({
                    region: {
                        latitude,
                        longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                    }
                })
            });

        await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                this.setState({
                    region: {
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                    }
                })
            },
            (error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)),
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._findMe();
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
    }
    render() {
        const { region } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    style={[styles.map, { width: this.state.width }]}
                    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                    onMapReady={() => console.log(this.state.region)}
                    showsUserLocation
                    followsUserLocation={true}
                    region={region}
                    showsMyLocationButton={true}
                    // style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                    textStyle={{ color: '#bc8b00' }}
                    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderColor: '#BC8B00' }}
                >
                    <Marker
                        coordinate={this.state.region}
                        title="Hello"
                        description="description"
                    />
                </MapView>
                {/* <Text>{this.state.region.latitude}</Text> */}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        padding: 30,
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    map: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: -1,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    },
});

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I wanted you share the solution to this bug on android platform.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Make custom button, and then onPress using animateToRegion go to users location.
2. The reason, you are seeing the button after reopening the app is due to repaint/rerender (which solves this issue). So in short if you cause a rerender the button will appear.

snippet to get the idea

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       bottomMargin: 1,
   };
 }
 <MapView
      showsUserLocation
      style={{
        marginBottom: this.state.bottomMargin,             // using state in styling
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
      }}
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
      onMapReady={() => this.setState({ bottomMargin: 0 })} // this will fire once onReady

 />
```

Comment: Hello @AmeerHamza, I faced the same issue and it does not work sadly :( and when I use my own button, It's work without any animation just navigates

Comment: Hi @OliverD, if you are using a custom button then you need to use the animatetoregion inorder to show the animations. If you want to use the existing button then use the code I posted, it will cause a rerender and button will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you I used animationToRegion it's work well, but when using the existing button provided and use your code not work well

Comment: @OliverD Great, I am happy it solved your problem kindly upvote the answer :) The above snippet should also work because I have used this hack multiple times.

Comment: Hey @AmeerHamza, can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361533/how-to-activate-gps-icon-in-react-native) question, please?